# Adapter not creating views in programmatically created recycler view after adding item decoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, spacing

I am programmatically creating `RecyclerView` assigning adapter to it and adding item decoration also.. but adapter is not creating views. When I removed item decoration its building fine. There is not issue with item decoration as I used that piece of code in xml created RecyclerView without any issues.

**Sample code is as below:**

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams recyclerViewLayoutParams =
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
recyclerViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(recyclerViewLayoutParams);
recyclerView.setClipToPadding(false);
ll_parent_layout.addView(recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getParent());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

// recyclerView.removeItemDecoration(gridSpacingItemDecoration);
// recyclerView.addItemDecoration(gridSpacingItemDecoration);

Adapter adapter = new Adapter(Activity.this, ResponseMap);

// linearSpacingItemDecoration = new LinearSpacingItemDecoration(R.dimen.margin8, adapter.getItemCount());
// recyclerView.removeItemDecoration(linearSpacingItemDecoration);
// recyclerView.addItemDecoration(linearSpacingItemDecoration);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: where is recyclerView.setAdapter method?

Comment: what is your item decoration?? you need to remember that item decoration draws **over** the list item content view

Comment: @Drim It;s there in the code. I just forgot to paste.

Comment: @Bhargav I know that and I want item decoration over my list item only but isn;t coming and no list item is being display

Comment: can you paste the code of your item decorator class

Comment: 'int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position

        if (position == 0) {
            outRect.left = spacing;
            outRect.right = spacing / 2 ;
            outRect.top = spacing;
            outRect.bottom = spacing;
        }
        '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with how item decorator class was getting initialized and reinitialzed.. I figured in after some time